# Can I replace a 7.25 inch electric coil with a 7 inch one?

Tags: stove, replacement

I have a small apartment stove/over combo made by Galaxy Appliances. The large burner is 7.25 inch in diameter. I cannot find a replacement that size. Can I use a 7 inch diameter replacement instead? Thank you.

Comment: why not?  ......

Comment: It may be possible but knowing the wattage of the original and the new one would be needed before being able to safely say yes. Or if the 7” is the same or lower wattage yes it would be safe. If the 7” is a higher wattage it could create a fire hazard in the wiring and or fry a controller.

Comment: Would the metal supports of the new burner slip through the current support ring? Would the new burner be off center when snapped in to the electrical connections?

Comment: It is possible that a burner advertised as 7 seven inch is 7.25 when measured.  Might be more important it has the same number of rings/circles of elements.  One with three rings not the same as four rings of same diameter.  Standard sizes can be different from measured size.